# Tentativa de leitura ou gravação em memória protegida

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, active-record

Eu tenho uma aplicação em `C#` que se conecta ao banco de dados `Oracle`. Para isso a aplicação faz uso do *NHibernate* (uma versão bem antiga) e do *Castle ActiveRecord*. Isso sempre deu certo, porém, agora quando eu tento fazer alguma consulta no banco eu recebo uma ***System.AcessViolationException***, que diz:

> Tentativa de leitura ou gravação em memória protegida. Normalmente, isso é uma indicação de que outra memória está danificada.

O intrigante é que em todos os outros computadores daqui, tudo funciona perfeitamente. Eu já vi muita coisa sobre isso nos últimos dias, mas nada tem me ajudado a solucionar isso. Inclusive eu procurei pelo erro em inglês:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

e acabei encontrando outras pessoas que tiveram esse problema com o *NHibernate* e/ou *ActiveRecord*. Infelizmente atualizar o *NHibernate* ou deixar de usar o *ActiveRecord* não é uma opção válida. Eu tenho certeza de que este erro não é específico dessas **libs**, mas eu não consigo achar uma solução pra isso.

O `stacktrace` da primeira `exception` é:

```
em System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.OCIServerAttach(OciHandle srvhp, OciHandle errhp, Byte[] dblink, Int32 dblink_len, MODE mode)
   em System.Data.OracleClient.TracedNativeMethods.OCIServerAttach(OciHandle srvhp, OciHandle errhp, String dblink, Int32 dblink_len, MODE mode)
   em System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)
   em System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions)
   em System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   em System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()
   em NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
```

**EDIT**

Desinstalei o Oracle que eu tinha na minha máquina e agora estou recebendo o erro:

> System.Data.OracleClient exige software cliente Oracle version 8.1.7 ou posterior.

Já reinstalei o *Instant Client* e o outro projeto que faz as mesmas conexões está funcionando normal...

Comment: Tente reinstalar o cliente do oracle. Já passei por issso e o problema era esse.

Comment: Irei fazer isso agora mesmo, é meio estranho porque eu tenho uma outra aplicação igual a esta nessa questão de conexão com o banco e esta segunda está funcionando.

Comment: Você pode estar tentando realizar uma tarefa não suportada pelo provider ou pelo driver. Esse erro ocorre quando um programa tenta acessar uma referencia de memória que não é dele.

Comment: @JoãoLuizGrigolettin, agora eu estou simplesmente tentando abrir a conexão com a System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection e estou recebendo este erro.

Comment: A última exceção pode não ser onde resida o problema, ela pode ser consequência de um erro anterior. Esteja certo disto.

Comment: @lsalamon, eu disse última querendo dizer a primeira. No caso, a última InnerException

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vou deixar registrado aqui como resolvi este problema, caso alguém se depare com o mesmo.

Este primeiro erro foi causado por que eu estava usando um banco de dados local x64 e meu **instant client** era x86. Eu não estava usando o banco local, mas de qualquer forma resolvi desinstalando banco. O segundo erro era porque o meu usuário estava sem permissão de leitura/escrita na pasta do **instant client**, então o que eu precisei fazer foi dar essas permissões para o meu usuário e reiniciar o PC.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, recentemente estava com o mesmo problema, um batch de execução funcionava muito bem e no batch seguinte o erro surgia, no caminho eu percebi os meus erros, onde ambos geravam a situação, as causas são:

• Create de um Command a partir de outro Command 
`var comandOracle = _comando`
• Número de parâmetros diferente da base destino (no meu caso de insert)